# Questions about Access-Control-Allow-Origin and CORS

Tags: http

According to the [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#resource-requests):

> 1. If the Origin header is not present terminate this set of steps. The request is outside the scope of this specification.

My interpretation is that the server is not responsible for returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in this situation, correct?

> 2. If the value of the Origin header is not a case-sensitive match for any of the values in list of origins do not set any additional headers and terminate this set of steps.

So only the origins listed in the white list will get the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header returned, otherwise nothing. Correct?

3. Is `ip_addr:port` a valid Origin value? For instance: `Origin: 127.0.0.1:8080`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Correct. The `origin` request header must be present to initiate a CORS request.
2. Correct. You will only receive CORS response headers if the `origin` that is sent is whitelisted.
3. Yes this is a valid `origin`. For more info read [RFC 6454 - Origin of a URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-4) and [RFC 3986 - Authority](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2).